# How to create a static html page with a dynamic TOC cursor

Tags: javascript, html

What's the easiest way to create a static user-manual html page with a table of contents that has a cursor that moves dynamically as the user scrolls the page? Are there any existing JavaScript libraries or frameworks that provide this functionality?

I am trying to do something very similar to this page: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a great detailed tutorial here (using Boostrap, affex, and scrollspy): http://www.codingeverything.com/2014/02/BootstrapDocsSideBar.html

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Bootstrap Scrollspy feature](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)